# Cucumber BDD for RAILS / ActiveRecord - Speedup slow tests by shimming out the database layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, cucumber, bdd

My company is using the [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) BDD test framework for a moderately large RAILS app.

It's slow.  Dog slow.  Just the single cucumber that I'm working on takes 30s-40s to run, and there's dozens and dozens of different test files.  It takes like an hour plus to run the whole thing.

Looking into things a bit, there's a huge amount of repetitive database work but the total data size is pretty small.  For example, I see slow statements like:

```
Given I have all the discussion threads for "fake user 47"
```

That takes 1000+ ms. The only thing it does is to take a few dozen rows of stock fixture data from a file on disk and load it into the database one row at a time.  It's not a huge quantity of data, a few KiB at most.  But once you add up all the overhead of ActiveRecord processing and converting it to a few dozen SQL statements, and then synchronously doing cross-process IPC to mysql to execute said statements ... well, it seems to add up.

Mysql itself is NOT the issue here, and switching to in-memory tables / etc has pretty much 0 impact on the run time of the tests.  The cucumber process runs at about 70% CPU utilization.

However, hitting the database is still a pretty expensive operation given that it's a cross-process request that has to go through multiple layers of adapters, data drivers and marshaling and whatnot on both sides, not to mention 2+ context switches per request.

So my theory is that if we were just storing data in, eg a simple hash table, then the tests would run a LOT faster.  (looking up how to do profiling in Ruby so I can prove this theory).

***Is it possible to run our test suite using a shimmed-out in-process "simulated" database layer?  Ideally, something super lightweight that ideally doesn't even need to deal with SQL at all, just implement whatever contract that ActiveRecord expects.***

Also, we seem to do the same setup multiple times.  One test will say *"Given I have data X"* and spend ages loading data X to do a few checks. Then another test will say *"Given I have data Y"*, clear the db, spend ages loading data Y, and do a few checks.  Then a 3rd test says *"Given I have data X"*, clears the db, and spends ages again reloading X.  And of course the 4th test probably uses data Y again....

***Is there a clean pattern to reuse test initialization code across scenarios?  Or to cache a particular initialized state?***

Comment: Do you have a combination of unit tests and cucumber tests? or is everything in cucumber?

Comment: Seems like you're over-testing. Cucumber is used for integrations tests so it doesn't make much sense to fake the database layer. You might consider only testing happy paths in cucumber and do edge-case testing in unit tests.

Comment: have you tried optimizing your test environment, e.g. are you encrypting passwords at user creation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "optimizing my test environment", but I am looking at optimization on multiple levels, including significant refactorings of our app's models and controllers which do far too much unneeded work.  Heh, I don't think user passwords even figure into most of our tests.

Comment: Also, we have both RSpec and Cucumber.  RSpecs cover individual models, but there are very complex interactions between the models and controllers, and those are covered by Cucumber.  I want to be able to run both levels of testing before each checkin.  For pre-ship "acceptance" testing, I'm willing to wait hours for the live tests to run with live data and pound a real db connection.  But that seems excessive for pre-checkin validation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer to your question. But as for the final part of the problem you can use [cucumber Global hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks). Since it is integration testing I suggest you populate the database according to the real life scenario. So wherever it is appropriate populate both data X and data Y before all the tests using cucumber hooks. With careful planning the time taken may be optimized quite a bit.

Comment: You should expound on that a bit.  That's one of the tactics I've tried.  Part of the complexity is that the tests are fragile to specifics of what's in the db.  There will be tests like "And user 'bob' has 4 friends" and the number is tuned to having a specific subset of the possible data.  So I could rewrite everything to load a set of fixtures once and then use the db in a mostly read-only fashion, but it's a non-trivial fix.  Also, it makes testing shallower since we would be testing mutation paths less often.

Comment: also, there's no need for the cucumber hooks to achieve what you are suggesting.  Standard 'Given' statements would work just fine.  However, I did use the hooks to write a "slow step detector" that prints a message any time a step takes >400ms.